# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type is less accessible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /User/
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(User U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                dc.Users.Add(U);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                U = null;
                ViewBag.Message = "Successfully register Done";
            }
        }
        return View(U);
    }

}
```

Comment: Inconsistent accessiblity: Parameter type ''Register.controllers.User' is less accessible than method 'UserController.register(RegisterFrom.Controllers.User)' .....   this is the actual error

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, but without the *full error message giving us the type and location in the code* it is something of a guess, that type `User` is protected or internal.